# Application started to redirect on every button click and pressed 'enter' in input

Tags: reactjs

I've been developing my first React application for a few days. Everything worked well. Now when i click any button or press enter in form, I'm redirected on same page with question mark `localhost:3000/?`.

I understand that could be usual behavior of browser and I understand that I am possible to fix it with `e.preventDefault()` on form submit and adding the `type="button"` to all buttons but **my question is: How this could happend?** How it could be working for a few days and stopped working now? **Is there any possibility that there is something what could cause it in my code?** What could have changed?

```
render() {
//...
// I don't have any 'onSubmit' in my form, but it worked for few days of development. I can fix it with adding function with e.preventDefault().
 <form className="someName">
   <input type="text" className={(this.state.editable?'editable':'locked')} value={this.props.task.name} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e,'name')} />
 </form>
//...
}
```

Comment: You are describing normal default form behavior so no way for us to know what was different before

Comment: It was not redirecting before (I don't know what have changed, that's why I'm asking here). So the usual behavior is to redirect when enter is pressed in form and there is no other way then prevent it manually?

Comment: Are you sure you had it as form since beginning? You can define inputs outside of form too, then it dont have that default behavior.